# WSO2 BPS Carbon unable to connect with studio

Tags: wso2, wso2-business-process

I can't connect the Developer Studio to the BPS.
I have the latest version of studio and the BPS version is the latest ( 3.6.0 ).
When I try to connect the server the Developer Studio check of the existance is positive, but when I try to check the password the result is
403 error forbidden.
The shell says WARN {org.owasp.csrfguard.log.JavaLogger} -  potential cross-site request forgery (CSRF) attack thwarted (user:, ip:127.0.0.1, method:POST, uri://services/AuthenticationAdmin, error:required token is missing from the request)

I can access through the browser

Comment: what do you mean by check the password? were you trying to log in to the admin console?

Comment: No, I can log into the admin console (by browser) but I can't by the developer studio

Answer (score 1):

You can try this method.

Locate to  `Owasp.CsrfGuard.Carbon.properties`
file in {BPS_HOME}/repository/conf/security and add the line below

> org.owasp.csrfguard.unprotected.Services=%servletContext%/services/*

Restart the BPS server and try to connect again

Hope this helps